# Kivy Text Input for Arabic Text

Tags: python, kivy, arabic, right-to-left

I'm trying to use Kivy's text input for Arabic text. I have an Arabic font set up with my text input but when I type into the input (in Arabic) I just get Arabic letters appearing from left to right (and they're not connected as Arabic letters should be when they're adjacent to each other).

Is there a way to get Kivy/text input to support RTL languages input that I'm missing (esp Arabic).

Here's my code,

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '300')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '500')


logger = logging.getLogger('')

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class EditorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()
        textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world', font_name='DroidKufi-Regular.ttf')
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

        f.add_widget(textinput)

        return f


if __name__ == '__main__':
    EditorApp().run()
```

The result of this code:

[image]

Comment: This is a known issue, I'm not sure if anyone is working directly on it but it's been discussed before. You might have more luck asking on the kivy irc channel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, Kivy TextInput support for right-to-left is [an open issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/1619) (checked 29/05/2015). Actually, Kivy is not supporting right-to-left not only to TextInput.

For static texts like labels , there is a hack by using [arabic_reshaper](https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper) and [python-bidi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bidi) ([reference](http://mpcabd.igeex.biz/python-arabic-text-reshaper/)):

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(u'اللغة العربية رائعة')
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
```

[image]

Yet, as for `TextInput` with a dynamic input, you had to override most of class methods to support RTL and you will end up like implementing the whole RTL support to kivy.

Here is an open attempt to implement [Kivy bidi support](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/2411). Another closed one: [Right-to-left labels support](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/1614).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this stuff. I've not encountered any of this before. Going to read into it and see if I can implement RTL in kivy myself..mm thoughts or advice?

Comment: @user772401 You are welcome, start about reading the PR [2411](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/2411) . Someone tried to use [pyfribidi](http://pyfribidi.sourceforge.net/) or python-bidi for this purpose. A harder choice but more efficient is to go with [Harfbuzz](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/HarfBuzz/).

Comment: Does this solution also work with hebrew? That could be really helpful.

Comment: @TalMoshel I dont think this library do it, but you can do the Hebrew version of it by replacing the  independent letters with their shaped alternatives

Comment: @BigOther I don't really understand what you are telling me to do? How do I replace the independent letter with her shaped alternative?

Answer (score 5):

So there was an answer that I luckily was able to get through and try out.

the links is here: https://github.com/hosseinofj/persian_textinput_kivy/blob/master/codes

Since it got deleted for not explaining, and not posting the code here, I'll do so myself, albeit the user who posted this link should be thanked somehow too!

Anyway, here is the code:

**test.kv**

```
<Ar_text@TextInput>:
    text: "whatever"
    multiline: 0
    size_hint: 1,1
    font_name: "data/unifont-11.0.02.ttf" # the font you want to use
    font_size: 26
    padding_y: [15,0] # can be changed
    padding_x: [self.size[0]-self._get_text_width(max(self._lines, key=len), self.tab_width, self._label_cached)-10,8]
```

**main.py**

```
'''
App demonstrating a Text input field which accepts Arabic script in kivy

'''


import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, StringProperty


class Ar_text(TextInput):
    max_chars = NumericProperty(20)  # maximum character allowed
    str = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Ar_text, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape("اطبع شيئاً"))


    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        if not from_undo and (len(self.text) + len(substring) > self.max_chars):
            return
        self.str = self.str+substring
        self.text = get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(self.str))
        substring = ""
        super(Ar_text, self).insert_text(substring, from_undo)

    def do_backspace(self, from_undo=False, mode='bkspc'):
        self.str = self.str[0:len(self.str)-1]
        self.text = get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(self.str))


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Ar_text()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

The trick with this is to use `arabic_shaper`

So at every update of the text, you provide the text input with a formatted string using the `arabic_shaper`.

There is still the fundamental issue that true RTL isn't there(the cursor is always to the right at the end of a string)

I added a repo with the sample code. It ran on Ubuntu. It should run on windows too if Kivy is properly installed

https://github.com/eliasaj92/arabic_text_input_kivy