# Having the Error "ImportError: No module named setupconfig" with kivy

Tags: python, kivy, python-import

Trying to run the script in the question: [Kivy Text Input for Arabic Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514853/kivy-text-input-for-arabic-text).

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class EditorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()
        textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world', font_name='DroidKufi-Regular.ttf')
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

        f.add_widget(textinput)

        return f


if __name__ == '__main__':
    EditorApp().run()
```

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I have installed `Cython` with `apt-get` and `kivy` with `pip` but still having this error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/assem/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-05-28_2.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy.test.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/kivy/app.py", line 324, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 167, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/kivy/graphics/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.instructions import Callback, Canvas, CanvasBase, \
   File "vbo.pxd", line 7, in init kivy.graphics.instructions (/tmp/easy_install-0Cj46_/Kivy-1.9.0/kivy/graphics/instructions.c:13615)
   File "compiler.pxd", line 1, in init kivy.graphics.vbo (/tmp/easy_install-0Cj46_/Kivy-1.9.0/kivy/graphics/vbo.c:5217)
   File "shader.pxd", line 5, in init kivy.graphics.compiler (/tmp/easy_install-0Cj46_/Kivy-1.9.0/kivy/graphics/compiler.c:2970)
   File "texture.pxd", line 3, in init kivy.graphics.shader (/tmp/easy_install-0Cj46_/Kivy-1.9.0/kivy/graphics/shader.c:9955)
   File "context_instructions.pxd", line 1, in init kivy.graphics.texture (/tmp/easy_install-0Cj46_/Kivy-1.9.0/kivy/graphics/texture.c:28975)
   File "context_instructions.pyx", line 29, in init kivy.graphics.context_instructions (/tmp/easy_install-0Cj46_/Kivy-1.9.0/kivy/graphics/context_instructions.c:16774)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/kivy/core/image/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
     from kivy.setupconfig import USE_SDL2
 ImportError: No module named setupconfig
```

How could I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an issue submitted to `kivy` about ["Setupconfig.py not installed with pip"](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2850), they seems fixed and closed it.

However, I fixed the error by re-installing `kivy` via `apt-get` instead of `pip`. I followed the installation steps from [official webpage](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
$ sudo apt-get install python-kivy
```