# Using Custom font in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to create a simple kivy software and I need to use custom Arabic font for `button.text`.

I've included the custom font in the file and tried but that is how it looks like:

[image]

I am not sure if it is an encoding problem or I need to use something different in Kivy

here is my code :

**main.py**

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window


class MyGrid(Widget):
    pass

class BackOffice(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BackOffice().run()
```

**backoffice.kv**

```
#:import utils kivy.utils


<MyGrid>
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex('#a1d0f4')
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height
        Label:
            text: 'logo here'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: ' vision logo goes here'
            GridLayout:
                cols:1
                Button:
                    size: 700, 120
                    size_hint: None, None # <---
                    background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0a74c4')
                    font_name: 'fonts/Shoroq-Font.ttf'
                    text: "إعدادت المستخدمين"
                    Image:
                        source: 'images/conference-256.png'
                        y: self.parent.y + 5
                        x: self.parent.x + 70



                Button:
                    text:'button'
                    background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0a74c4')
                Button:
                    text:'button'
                    background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0a74c4')
                Button:
                    text:'button'
                    background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0a74c4')
        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            Button:
                text: 'button'
                background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#ff0000')
            Button:
                text: 'button'
                background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0a74c4')
            Label:
                text: 'some text here'
```

*** update ***
I also tried to use Arabic reshaper based on [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514853/kivy-text-input-for-arabic-text) but it still gives the same result !! as the question was about `Textinput`, not text viewing in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to use [`arabic.reshaper`](https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper) and [`bidi.algorithm`](https://pypi.org/project/python-bidi/)

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class MyGrid(Widget):
    bidi_text = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(u"إعدادت المستخدمين")
        self.bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)


class BackOffice(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BackOffice().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:import utils kivy.utils


<MyGrid>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex('#a1d0f4')
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height
        Label:
            text: 'logo here'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: ' vision logo goes here'
            GridLayout:
                cols:1
                Button:
                    size: 700, 120
                    size_hint: None, None # <---
                    background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0a74c4')
                    font_name: 'fonts/Shoroq-Font.ttf'
                    text: root.bidi_text
                    font_size: sp(20)

                    Image:
                        source: 'images/conference-256.png'
                        y: self.parent.y + 5
                        x: self.parent.x + 70



                Button:
                    text:'button'
                    background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0a74c4')
                Button:
                    text:'button'
                    background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0a74c4')
                Button:
                    text:'button'
                    background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0a74c4')
        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            Button:
                text: 'button'
                background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#ff0000')
            Button:
                text: 'button'
                background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0a74c4')
            Label:
                text: 'some text here'
```

## Output

[image: Result]