# RTL input for kivy/ Persian input in kivy and kivymd

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd, farsi, rtl-language

I am using kivy to develop .apk for android, and I am having trouble set RTL language ( Persian so to speak) to be suitably used as user input. Instead I am observing characters are shown as  that are unrecognizable characters. Just note that I can use reshaper and bidi to fix RTL MDlabels, but for user inputs I couldn`t find a way. I need to see correct Persian (Kurdish, Arabic, ...) letters whilst getting user input.

Comment: Have you tested this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53592755)? make sure to use universal font like Ariel.ttf to support both Persian and English together.