# The problem of Kivy Python to display Persian and Arabic text

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, arabic-support

When I use Farsi or Arabic, it displays multi-line text from bottom to top.

1. I face this problem when I use a large number of Persian texts.
2. This problem does not occur in short texts because the screen does not send it to the next line.
3. In a long text, when the screen is reduced, it goes to the next line, it faces this problem.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
#:import arabic_reshaper arabic_reshaper
#:import get_display bidi.algorithm.get_display

Screen:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True
            index:1

            MDCard:
                id: md_card
                orientation: "vertical"
                padding: "8dp"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 300, 300
                #pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

                MDLabel:
                    font_name: 'font/Sahel.ttf'
                    text: get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape('تست نام'))
                    halign: "right"

                MDSeparator:
                    height: "1dp"

                MDLabel:
                    font_name: 'font/Sahel.ttf'
                    halign: "right"
                    text: get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape('این یک متن فارسی صرفا برای تست است در کیوی نمایش آن اشتباه از پایین به سمت بالا است.'))

'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Test().run()
```

It should display top to bottom, thanks in advance for any help.

This is the image you see in the output of this code.

[checkmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aBTc.png).

what i want:

- Using the image editing program, I moved the text to make it correct.
- What I want to display properly, from top to bottom.

[checkmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hef4g.png).

Comment: What exactly you want ?

Comment: I want to display a long text from top to bottom.

Comment: But it displays from bottom to top, It is clear in the image I uploaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kivy Text Input for Arabic Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514853/kivy-text-input-for-arabic-text)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `python-bidi` and `arabic_reshaper`.

```
import arabic_reshaper
import bidi.algorithm

reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape("متن فارسی")
bidi_text = bidi.algorithm.get_display(reshaped_text)
```

then use `bidi_text` as the Kivy label text.

check [this link](https://medium.com/@ahmedfgad/supporting-arabic-alphabet-in-kivy-for-building-cross-platform-applications-7a1e7c14a068) to learn how to use these libraries properly.

Comment: This is how I used it
get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape('تست نام'))
But unfortunately, if it is long, it displays from the bottom to the top.

Comment: try setting `rtl=True` as the Label attribute.

Comment: I did it but it didn't work

Comment: try setting `valign` for the Label

Comment: If you guys can send a sample code, I would appreciate it, That way I understand better.

Comment: (valign) --> I did it, but unfortunately it didn't work, please send a code sample. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First create Farsi Component as I done here

```py
# components/FaTextInputComponent.py
from arabic_reshaper import reshape
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty
from kivymd.uix.textfield.textfield import MDTextField # You can use kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput insted if MDTextField


class FaTextInput(MDTextField):
    max_chars = NumericProperty(20)  # maximum character allowed
    str = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("font_name", "Vazir")
        kwargs.setdefault("font_family", "Vazir")

        kwargs.setdefault("font_name_helper_text", "Vazir")
        kwargs.setdefault("font_name_hint_text", "Vazir")
        kwargs.setdefault("font_name_max_length", "Vazir")

        kwargs.setdefault("font_context", "Vazir")
        kwargs.setdefault("text_language", "fa-IR")
        self._helper_text_label.font_name = "Vazir"
        self._hint_text_label.font_name = "Vazir"

        super(FaTextInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        if not from_undo and (len(self.text) + len(substring) > self.max_chars):
            return

        self.str = self.str + substring
        self.text = get_display(reshape(self.str))
        substring = ""
        super(FaTextInput, self).insert_text(substring, from_undo)

    def do_backspace(self, from_undo=False, mode="bkspc"):
        self.str = self.str[0 : len(self.str) - 1]
        self.text = get_display(reshape(self.str))
```

Set global fonts and colors as I did for KivyMD

```py
# utils/Theme.py
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager


class Theme:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.theme_cls = ThemeManager()

        self.setup_palette()
        self.setup_font()

    @property
    def get_theme_cls(self):
        return self.theme_cls

    def setup_palette(self):
        from utils.constants import COLOR

        self.theme_cls.colors.update(COLOR)

        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "DeepPurple"
        self.theme_cls.primary_light_hue = "50"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "100"
        self.theme_cls.primary_dark_hue = "200"

        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Pink"
        # self.theme_cls.accent_light_hue = "50"
        # self.theme_cls.accent_hue = "100"
        # self.theme_cls.accent_dark_hue = "200"

        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

    def setup_font(self):
        from utils.constants import FONTS

        # LabelPango.
        for font in FONTS:
            LabelBase.register(**font)

        self.theme_cls.font_styles.update(
            {
                "H1": ["VazirExtraBold", 52, False, -1.5],
                "H2": ["VazirExtraBold", 46, False, -0.5],
                "H3": ["VazirBold", 40, False, 0],
                "H4": ["VazirBold", 34, False, 0.25],
                "H5": ["VazirSemiBold", 28, False, 0],
                "H6": ["VazirMedium", 22, False, 0.15],
                "Subtitle1": ["Vazir", 16, False, 0.15],
                "Subtitle2": ["VazirMedium", 14, False, 0.1],
                "Body1": ["Vazir", 16, False, 0.5],
                "Body2": ["Vazir", 14, False, 0.25],
                "Button": ["VazirMedium", 14, True, 1.25],
                "Caption": ["Vazir", 12, False, 0.4],
                "Overline": ["Vazir", 10, True, 1.5],
            }
        )
```

Create screen manager that loads components to your app

```py
# utils/ScreenProvider.py
import os
from importlib import import_module

from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.transition import MDFadeSlideTransition
from utils.BaseScreenManager import ScreenManager


class ScreenProvider:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """Loading Components and Screens"""

        # Load RTL components
        self.load_components()

        # Load and import Screens
        screen_files = list(filter(self.is_screen_file, os.listdir("screens")))
        self.__screen_manager = ScreenManager(transition=MDFadeSlideTransition())
        blank_screen = MDScreen(name="blank")
        self.__screen_manager.add_widget(blank_screen)

        for screen_file in screen_files:
            screen_module = import_module(
                f"screens.{screen_file[:-3]}"
            )  # Remove the `.py` extention
            screen_class_name = screen_file[:-3]
            screen_class = getattr(screen_module, screen_class_name)
            screen = screen_class(
                name=screen_class_name[:-6]
            )  # Remove `Screen.py` suffix
            self.__screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        # Get Login screen and remove blank page
        self.__screen_manager.select_start_screen()
        self.__screen_manager.remove_widget(blank_screen)

    def is_screen_file(self, file_name: str) -> bool:
        return file_name.__contains__("Screen.py")

    def is_component_file(self, file_name: str) -> bool:
        return file_name.__contains__("Component.py")

    def load_components(self, *args, **kwargs):
        components_files = list(
            filter(self.is_component_file, os.listdir("components"))
        )

        for component_file in components_files:
            component_module = import_module(
                f"components.{component_file[:-3]}"
            )  # Remove the `.py` extention
            component_class_name = component_file[:-12]  # Remove `Component.py` suffix
            component_class = getattr(component_module, component_class_name)
            Factory.register(classname=component_class_name, cls=component_class)

    @property
    def screen_manager(self):
        return self.__screen_manager
```

In `main.py` file load Custom Screen Manager as I did

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from os import environ
from pathlib import Path

environ.update(
    {
        # "KCFG_KIVY_LOG_LEVEL": "error",
        # "KIVY_NO_CONSOLELOG": "0",
        "KIVY_NO_FILELOG": "0",
    }
)

from kivy.config import Config

Config.read("settings.ini")
Config.set("kivy", "config_version", 27)
Config.set("kivy", "log_enable", 0)
Config.set("input", "%(name)s", "")


import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from utils.ScreenProvider import ScreenProvider
from utils.Theme import Theme

# TODO: Update to 2.2.1
# FIXME: Version 2.2.1 has compilation error for unknown reason
kivy.require("2.2.0")




class CoreApp(MDApp):
    def build(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CoreApp, self).build(*args, **kwargs)

        # Set up theme
        self.theme_cls = Theme().get_theme_cls
        self.title = "MyApp"
        self.icon = "assets/icons/logo_transparent.png"

        # Kivy files setup
        kv_files_path = str(Path().parent / "views")
        self.kv_directory = kv_files_path
        self.load_all_kv_files(kv_files_path)

        # Set up screens
        screen_manager = ScreenProvider().screen_manager
        self.screen_manager = screen_manager

        return self.screen_manager

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CoreApp()

    # TODO: Should update it to read it from env
    async_run = True

    if async_run:
        import asyncio

        asyncio.run(app.async_run())
    else:
        app.run()
```

Now just Use `FaTextInput` in `.kv` file same as `TextInput` or `MDTextField`

Note: You may need install `bidi` and `arabic_reshaper` by

```bash
pip install arabic-reshaper python-bidi
```

Answer (score -1):

[Link >>> A question that was asked to the programmer of her library and still has not been answered.](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/7918)

After many investigations, I realized that the problem is from this part, but I can't make it like a mirror to solve the problem of displaying Persian and Arabic text.

**Lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text_init_.py line 760**

```
def refresh(self):
    '''Force re-rendering of the text'''
    self.resolve_font_name()

    # first pass, calculating width/height
    sz = self.render()
    self._size_texture = sz
    self._size = (sz[0], sz[1])


    # if no text are rendered, return nothing.
    width, height = self._size
    # print('width, height : ', width, height)
    if width <= 1 or height <= 1:
        self.texture = self.texture_1px
        return

    # create a delayed texture
    texture = self.texture
    if texture is None or \
            width != texture.width or \
            height != texture.height:
        texture = Texture.create(size=(width, height),
                                 mipmap=self.options['mipmap'],
                                 callback=self._texture_fill)
        texture.flip_vertical()
        texture.add_reload_observer(self._texture_refresh)
        self.texture = texture
    else:
        texture.ask_update(self._texture_fill)
```

This discussion is for guidance and help to solve problems
I spent a lot of time to find the problem. It seems that if it shows this part like a mirror, the problem will be solved.
Changes in texture.